# Unable to boot from cloned drive using DCFLDD

Tags: boot, ssd, disk-image

Original system drive is 1TB NVME M.2 SSD. running Ubuntu 22.04.
created an image file using DCFLDD running off a Live USB on said system.
Moved the image file to another system, and restored it successfully to a 1TB external 2.5 SSD drive.
Using Gparted i verified the partitions appear identical and was able to access the data.
When I attempted to reboot from the cloned drive, at first the Ubuntu logo showed up for a while, then
a black screen appeared, displaying:

```
You are in emergency mode. 
After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot.
```

I have also uploaded the journalctl output from the failed boot attempt:

pastebin.com/A7YF1cMh

What is the problem here, and how do I login to view the system logs and figure out the cause of the problem?

Excerpt of Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary:

```
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       zfs_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 16.10 on sdb3
OS#2:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sda2
OS#3:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on sdb4

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (sda1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; are you hoping we guess?  Have you ensured the UUIDs are still UUIDs; ie. they are **unique** otherwise booting is *undefined* & problems are expected.. Did you allow for that in *cloning*, as you're rather light with specifics.

Comment: You typically have to reinstall grub. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  I always suggest new install & restore from backup. Good test that backup includes all your data & configurations while still having old install to correct backup, if necessary.

Comment: Updated the OS version

Comment: If I run Boot-Repair and have multiple bootable disk drives attached, how do you tell the utility which device to report on ?

Comment: The cloned device is "/dev/sdb",  Boot-Repair report is at:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h2tGBqqQvZ/

Comment: /dev/sda is the disk I've booted up from to run the Boot-Repair utility.    /dev/sdb is the cloned drive which gets me into emergency mode when it is the boot drive.        I have also uploaded the journalctl output from the failed boot attempt:

pastebin.com/A7YF1cMh

Comment: I figured out the cause of this problem.
in /etc/fstab there were 3 automount lines for devices not existing on the backup machine. so the mount fails for all 3.
In 20.04 it didn't cause a boot issue but on 22.04 it does.
Commented out those 3 auto mounts and backup system is up and runing.
I am surprised the journalctl output didn't clearly say this was the cause for entering emergency mode.